# Sending NSString to viewController returns a null

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I sent a NSString to a viewController, tried to log it from another viewController, and it turned null. My code is below

---

Edit: Im deleting all code and showing my code from my application. Because I am still getting (null)

### HabitViewController.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HabitViewController : UITableViewController {

    NSString *cellName2;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *cellName2;

@end
```

### HabitViewController.m

```
@synthesize cellName2;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%@",cellName2);

}
```

---

### DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {

    NSString *cellName;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *cellName;

@end
```

### DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

#import "HabitViewController.h"

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize cellName;

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    cellName = @"Hello World";

    HabitViewController *obj = [[HabitViewController alloc] init];

    obj.cellName2 = cellName;
}
```

I left a lot of code out, because they had nothing to do with my problem.

---

### Edit

Based on Jsdodgers comments and answer, I have updated My question :

habitViwController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HabitViewController : UITableViewController {

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *cellName2;

@end
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%@",self.cellName2);

}
```

---

DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {

}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *cellName;

@end
```

.m

```
@synthesize cellName;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    cellName = @"Hello World";

    HabitViewController *obj = [[HabitViewController alloc] init];

    obj.cellName2 = self.cellName;

    [self configureView];


}
```

But I still dont have any success. Still says (null)

Comment: I do not see anywhere in the code where the two view controllers are interacting with each other in any way.

Comment: I don't think this is your real code. SendingViewController has no cellName2 property.

Comment: This: `obj.cellName2 = cellName;` shouldn't compile since `obj` is a `SendingViewController` and therefore doesn't have a `cellName2`.

Comment: Look at the receiverViewController.h

Comment: And no this isnt my real code, its like it, but I changed names and things to make more understandable

Comment: Sorry I had made a typo in the code, now it more correct

Comment: When you give us code that you haven't actually compiled and run and encountered the problem in, you're just making it harder for everyone to figure out what the problem is. This code doesn't have the bug you're talking about, but it does have a bunch of other bugs. Without actually knowing what your program looks like, all we can do is guess blindly.

Comment: Debuggers are great for this sort of problem. Have you tried it and did it give any useful information?

Comment: I updated the code a lot, but still getting error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have two different variables in your ReceiverViewController.

One of them is called `cellName2`, which you are creating through `NSString *cellName2`. The other is called `_cellName2` which you are creating through `@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *cellName2;`.

The first you can call in your ReceiverViewController through `cellName2...`. The second, you can call through either `_cellName2...` or `self.cellName2`.

When you do `obj.cellName2 = ...`, you are setting the `_cellName2`, not `cellName2`. Thus, when you print `cellName2`, it is correctly null as you have not set it yet.

I would suggest completely removing the `NSString *cellName2;` from your code. Same goes for the `cellName` in your other class.

Comment: I think I follow you, but not sure. Anyway i deleted both the NSStrings for cellName and cellName2. The problem remains tho. So so I need to change something else?

Comment: do I need to set a pushToViewController method?

Comment: it is possible but then viewDidLoad would not run, which would mean that (null) is being printed from elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, so do you not see anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Ok, I ran it in my own simulator and got it working. You still have to get rid of the NSString *cellLabel2 and get rid of the @synthesize, and when you print it do `NSLog(@"%@",self.cellLabel2);` (make sure you do `self.`).

Comment: Also, I don't know where you are adding the view to your view heirarchy, but I will assume that you are and you just did not post the full code, otherwise it wouldn't print (null). Is that correct?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by adding view to hierechy

Comment: Just by `[someNavigationController pushViewController:controller];`, `[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES]` or some other similar method that presents the view controller for the user.

Comment: Oh, would setting the view as a class on a storyboard view work? And sorry to bother you so much, But I still cant get it to stop saying null

Comment: I update the question to show what the code looks like now

Comment: try doing `obj.cellName2 = @"Hello World";` instead of `obj.cellName2 = self.cellName;`.

Comment: same results as before

Comment: Is this the same code as yours when you got it working in the simulator?

Comment: It's the same, except instead of `[self configureView];` (which I assume is one of your methods), I have `[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj];`

Comment: I think that is definataitely the problem, but I have no idea what to put there

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edited question, I think you have simply not synthesized `cellName2` in your ReceiverViewController.

Use the `@synthesize` statement.

**edit**

Instantiating and setting the value of the Receiving View Controller:

```
ReceiverViewController *rvc = [[ReceiverViewController alloc] init];
rvc.stringValue = @"Hello world :)";
[self presentViewController:rvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: This is right, infact, because I tested it before posting my answer. The OP won't get a build error (but will get a warning only), because a private string variable with the same name is declared in the interface.

Comment: I have synthesized it

Comment: And that doesn't solve the problem? 
I tested two view controllers with the same structure and adding the synthesize statement removed the null logs for me.

Comment: still getting null log. Is the code above the same as your sample project?

Comment: Yes, it's essentially the same. I simply instantiate the Receiving VC and set the property `cellName2` belonging to Receiver VC.

Comment: I have updated my answer. If you still have this problem, I would suggest you upload the project on github if possible so I can look at your actual code.